# Informatica pass parameter to workflow that already has a parameter file

Tags: parameter-passing, informatica-powercenter

**Question:**
In Informatica Powercenter 9.6.1 hf3, is it possible to send a parameter to a workflow that already is using a parameter file?

E.g., could I refer to a parameter file from another parameter file? And make the workflow use that one?

**Background:**
I am trying to pass a parameter 'INTERFACE_NAME' to a workflow that is called from another workflow.
using `pcmd startworkflow... -paramfile <the param file>`, I can pass a parameter file in which I set the variable.

**Problem:**
However, there are many more environment variables that are specified in a global parameter file that the workflow also needs, and I do not want to add them to this little param file. This file is specified in the workflow itself.

As such, can the workflow use both param files?
OR is there a way to refer to a param file (with global settings) from another param file (with only the run-specific settings e.g. filepattern)?
OR another solution, e.g. dynamically create the file (should be a one-liner)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question. However if you've got a parameterfile in workflow definition (e.g. /home/user/primaryParamFile.param) and you will invoke the workflow with `pmcmd startworkflow... -paramfile /home/user/secondaryParamFile.param`, only the latter one will be used. The primaryParamFile will not be used at all. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - yes this is what my question was about. But is there a way to invoke all parameters from two files without copy-pasting the params from one file into the other, and using that file? I would like to just have a single point of storage of params, AND pass one param value to a workflow run instance. (e.g. a filepattern that differs per workflow run)

Comment: Nope. It's not possible to use more then one parameterfile for workflow. What you can try is use a paramenter file for a Warkflow AND one for a Session. I'm not sure if it will get the parameter from both or just one - you'll have to try this out for yourself.

Comment: ah and then pass the parameter from the session into the workflow or something like that...?

Comment: You can't pass anything to workflow parameterfile once the workflow has been started. As part of workflow initialization the parameterfile is read, and all later changes to the file will not be seen by the workflow. But one session can generate a file that another session is configured to use.

Comment: So this would explain an issue that I now found... updating the existing parameter file and use that in the next task didnt work. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Like I said - in this case you need to indicate the updated parameter file in the Session properties.

Comment: maybe i misread your comment - is it also not possible to pass a value to a workflow parameter file that is called through pcmcd from a running workflow? That 'child' workflow has not yet been started as per your words. This would happen directly after updating the parm file.

Comment: If a parameterfile will be updated before the workflow is started - it's perfectly fine. Like I said: workflow reads its parameterfile upon initialization. If any session WITHIN this running workflow ought to use some extra param, it needs to use its own parameterfile - a session defined parameterfile.

Comment: so weird you understandably write "If a parameterfile will be updated before the workflow is started - it's perfectly fine"...BUT the workflow that is started using the parameter file that is updated AFTER the run, actually shows the POST-update parameter value in its logfile. It seems completely impossible. CMD Task 'echo A>paramfile' --> call workflow Q -->cmd task 'echo B > param file' --> call workflow Q.... workflow log shows 'B' (the last value) in both runs...

Comment: Not sure I understand the scenario here. Try a workflow with two command tasks and $$MyParam=AAA in parameterfile; 1st. WF command task to do "echo $$MyParam=BBB > paramfile"; 2nd WF command task to do "echo $$MyParam > test.out"; 3 check the output. I'd expect paramfiel to be "$$MyParam=BBB" and test.out file to have "AAA"